What's a simple proof for solutions to a non homogeneous 2nd order linear recurrence relation?
So i have this 2nd order recurrence relation, n starts at 1, $$
A_{n} = -4A_{n-1} - 3A_{n-2} + 5(-2)^n
$$
and it is given that this equation satisfies it: $$A_{n}=-5(-2)^n$$  Main question is why is the general solution to the recurrence relation the homogeneous solution + the particular solution and could it be explained using elementary mathematics, given my total lack of background in math?
First thing I tried out of hopelessness was to subtract $5(-2)^n$ from $A_{n}$ to get a homogeneous sequence but realised that it wouldn't work given recursion would mean for each term there is some multiplicity of $5(-2)^n$ added to it due to recursion. Then I analyzed the sequence of $-5(-2)^n$, which gives 10,-20,40,-80,.., and realised that the sequence of
$-5(-2)^n$ seemingly didn't have any contributions from the homogeneous solution of the recurrence relation, meaning the coefficients to the homogeneous solution were zero. So if the sequence were to look different from 10,-20,40,-80,.., it means that there is some contribution from the homogeneous part. Then I analyzed the general solution of this recurrence relation $B(-1)^n + C(-3)^n  + (-5)(-2)^n$ and I got nothing out of it.

$-5(-2)^n$ is not an equation; it is a value.  What does it mean for it to "satisfy" a recurrence relation?  Please don't use salutations like "Thanks".  Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, please post them separately.  Please use proper grammar, including proper capitalization.

@D.W. "Satisfy" came from this question:
Verify that $a_n = A(-2)^n$, where $A$ is a constant to be determined, satisfies
$$ a_{n+2} + 4a_{n+1} + 3a_n = 5(-2)^n. $$

If you reworded your question in that form, it would be more understandable.

@D.W. You're right. I'm sorry.

Suppose you have two solutions to the difference equation, call them $A_n$ and $A'_n$. Then we know that:
$$\begin{align} A_n & = -4 A_{n-1} - 3 A_{n-2} + 5(-2)^n \\
A'_n & = -4 A'_{n-1} - 3 A'_{n-2} + 5(-2)^n\end{align}$$
just by definition. But look at what happens if we subtract the second equation from the first one:
$$(A_n - A'_n) = -4(A_{n-1} - A'_{n-1}) - 3(A_{n-2} - A'_{n-2})$$
So if we define $H_n = A_n - A'_n$, we see that $H_n$ is a solution to the homogeneous difference equation $H_n = -4 H_{n-1} - 3 H_{n-2}$. And that's true for any pair of solutions to the original equation, meaning that if we choose one solution in particular (i.e. the "particular solution"), we can reach any other solution of the difference equation by adding an appropriate solution of the homogeneous equation.
It takes a bit of extra work to demonstrate why, but it turns out that every solution $H_n$ of the homogeneous equation can be written as $H_n = B(-1)^n + C(-3)^n$, meaning that if you're already given the particular solution $A_{pn} = -5(-2)^n$ you can just add those together to get the general solution.

I assume the two solutions have to be particular solutions, in order to remove $-5(-2)^n$, but then the general solution uses one homogeneous and one particular so I am a little confused at this part. Thank you.

The idea is that for any particular solution you choose, you can reach any other particular solution by adding the right homogeneous solution.

Thanks a lot, I appreciate the help truly.

It helps to write it as
$$A_n +4A_{n - 1} + 3A_{n - 2} = 5(-2)^n.$$
This can written compactly as
$$(TA)(n) = 5(-2)^n,$$
where $TA$ is the sequence which is defined for $n \geq 3$ by
$$(TA)(n) = A_n +4A_{n - 1} + 3A_{n - 2}.$$
A sequence $B$ is a solution to the Homogenous equation if and only if $(TB)(n) = 0$ for all $n \geq 3$. A sequence $A$ is a particular solution if $(TA)(n) = 5(-2)^n$ for all $n \geq 3$. Thus, if $A_0$ is a particular solution and $B$ is a solution to the homogenous equation, then $(T(A_0 + B))(n) = (TA_0 + TB)(n) = TA_0(n) + TB(n) = 5(-2)^n$ for $n \geq 3$. Conversely, if $A_0$ is a particular solution, and $A$ is another particular solution, then $(T(A - A_0))(n) = TA(n) - TA_0(n) = 5(-2)^n - 5(-2)^n = 0$ for $n \geq 3$, so $A - A_0$ is a solution of the homogenous equation.

It seems redundant to add the homogeneous solution given sequence A, the particular sequence, already equals $5(−2)^n$ for n larger or equal to 3. Two things i note: you start your sequence at 3 which means initial values/conditions arent part of the recursion rule? Also it is possible for there to have two particular solutions? Thanks

I think I get it. Thanks for the help. I totally missed the fact that the goal is to find a general solution for any initial conditions. Given any different particular solution, there is a corresponding homogeneous solution such tha t it fits some intiial condition
